# Custom exception in Java with external message

Tags: java, exception

We just started with exceptions in Java in University and I am sitting on this task for quite a time and I still couldn't get much further.

The task is to customize an exception with a message depending on the parameters in the constructor. My idea was to write an extra method for the message but I am struggling to access the variables in the parameter

Here is what I have so far

```java
import java.util.Calendar;

public class BadUpdateTimeException extends Exception{

    private final boolean b;
    private final Calendar cal;
    
    public BadUpdateTimeException(Calendar cal, boolean b) {
        super(message());
        this.b = b;
        this.cal = cal;
    }
    
    private static String message() {
        if(b == true) {
            String s = "Update time is earlier than the last update: ";
            return s;
        }else {
            String s = "Update time is in the future: ";
            return s;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `static` prevents you from accessing instance fields, remove it. But in this case because of the execution order, you should pass `b` as a parameter to `message`.

Comment: But if I do so, I can't access it in super

Comment: But if I remove the static, message in super won't work any more as my compiler says.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that you are calling the superclass's constructor, which has to be done before anything else.

Thus, you cannot access fields such as `b` in your `message` method, since they are not set yet.

Change the first line of your constructor to

```
super(message(b));
```

and the `message` method to

```
private static String message(boolean b)
```

This will make the message method work with a local copy of the value which will later be assigned to the class field.

Comment: Wow thanks for the fast and helpful response! Got it now!!:)

Comment: You can upvote and/or accept this answer :)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should not use class' parameters in the static method; you have to delegate it via the method's parameter. Then you get a pretty working solution.

```java
public class BadUpdateTimeException extends Exception{

    public BadUpdateTimeException(Calendar cal, boolean b) {
        super(createMessage(cal, b));
    }
    
    private static String createMessage(Calendar cal, boolean b) {
        if (b)
            return "Update time is earlier than the last update: ";
        
        return "Update time is in the future: ";
    }
}
```